# Possessive apostrophes with names in speech marks

Tags: possessives, apostrophe, speech

I'm translating a text that refers to a person who goes by a nickname, so in the text this nickname is always shown in speech marks - "El Cuco". How do I use a possessive apostrophe correctly with a name in speech marks? For example, at one point they're talking about this person's version of events about a murder, would I say: "El Cuco's" version of events, placing the apostrophe within the speech marks?

Comment: @Laurel, well, you're right that they're basically duplicates. Do we always close the second one? or do we sometimes close the first if I've written a more comprehensive answer here? xD

Answer (score 2):

**It's best to rephrase and avoid the entire problem**.

[That's even what the style guides say](http://www.grammarunderground.com/plurals-and-possessives-of-movie-titles-in-quote-marks.html). Just don't do it at all.

The best solution would be to use quotes only once or not at all: *Bob El Cuco Roberts*; *Bob Roberts*, *known to the underworld as El Cuco* ("*Cuckoo*"); or *Bob Roberts* ("*El Cuco*") only at the first mention and then simply *El Cuco* on every occasion after that. In a script, you might even use *EC*. There's no reason at all that your translation needs to follow the foreign orthography of the original text, any more than you should be adding ¿ or 」 marks to English sentences.

If you have a professor or house style guide that insists that you must always use sneer quotes around aliases, you should just avoid using them as much as possible. Use *Bob Roberts* or *Roberts* or other descriptors instead of the nickname.

If there is no way around it because it's entirely out of your hands, use *X of "El Cuco"* instead of either *"El Cuco"'s X* or *"El Cuco's" X*.